# How do I prove the following statement about the complement of a cartesian product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, products

How do I prove that this statement is true?

> $$(A\times B)^C=\left(A^C\times B\right)\cup\left(A\times B^C\right)\cup\left(A^C\times B^C\right)$$

Comment: When you take an $(a,b) \in A \times B$, it means $a \in A$ and $b\in B$. Taking an $(a,b) \in \left( A \times B \right)^c$, is basically the negation of that, so it is $a \not\in A \textbf{ or } b \not\in B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just consider the element method. Suppose $(x,y)\in \left(A\times B\right)^C$. Then either $x\not\in A$, or $y\not\in B$. This leaves you three possibilities: $x\not\in A$ and $y\in B$, $x\in A$ and $y\not\in B$, or $x\not\in A$ and $y\not\in B$ (and one of these must be true). Respectively these three possibilities correspond to the sets $\left(A^C\times B\right)$, $\left(A\times B^C\right)$, and $\left(A^C\times B^C\right)$, so taking the union of these sets gives you the same thing as $\left(A\times B\right)^C$.

Comment: Why do we need an additional term $ A^C \times B^C$ since $(A^C \times B^C) \subset (A^C \times B )(A \times B^C)$

Comment: @Xenidia That's actually not true. Let's pick a specific example: Suppose we are considering $A$ and $B$ to be subsets of $\{0,1\}$ with $A=\{0\}$, $B=\{0\}$. Then $A^C\times B^C=\{(1,1)\}$ while $A^C\times B=\{(1,0)\}$ and $A\times B^C=\{0,1\}$. Notice that $(1,1)\not\in\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$.  I think of this situation like a square with two perpendicular lines cutting it into 4 pieces. $A\times B$ lies in one corner of this square while $A^C\times B^C$ lies in the opposite corner.